# Com calls to 32bit application on 64bit server slow

Tags: c#, performance, com, 64-bit, 32-bit

I have an application that I have just migrated to Windows 2008 R2 64bit. In  essence it is a C# .NET 4.0 WCF application that makes a dynamic call to a 32bit COM application written in VC6 C++.

When I was running this on my desktop which is Windows 7 32bit the COM calls were considerably faster.

The server ought to be an order of magnitude more powerful (although in a HOSTED environment)

Are there any quick/easy things I can check to try and get to the bottom of this? I am due today to get alook at the resources allocated to the virtual machine but in the mean time..

Is this a 64bit calling 32bit COM thing?

Thank you!

Comment: The solution would be to compile the COM application against the x64 platform.  There should be no reason a newer version of Visual Studio ( i.e. Visual C 6 was Visual Studio 6 at the time they were just marketed as seperate programs ).

Comment: Too many missing details.  Is this an out-of-process COM server?  Does it run on the same machine?  What is "hosted", does it actually run in a virtual machine?  COM+?  Does the managed code run in AnyCPU?  Is this an apartment threaded object?

Answer (score 5):

Running 32-bit code from 64-bit processes is very time-consuming, because it involves the Windows on Windows subsystem (WoW). 64-bit code and 32-bit code cannot be run within the same process, which means that **all calls** from your code to the 32-bit dll must pass process and architecture boundaries, which involves some heavy data marshalling and function call marshalling.

http://blog.mattmags.com/2007/06/30/accessing-32-bit-dlls-from-64-bit-code/

Do some profiling to measure the performance of your app in different situations.

- Compile to Any-CPU, run on x64
- Compile to x64, run on x64
- Compile to x86, run on x64

Then do what gives you the most performance.

**However...**

If you have access to the COM library source code, the very best thing would be to recompile it on the x64 platform.